# Essa é uma boa maneira de manter minha API segura?

Tags: segurança, rest, autenticação

Minha aplicação consiste de uma API nodejs no *backend* mas também estou criando a [implementação de referência](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_refer%C3%AAncia) de um cliente JavaScript, que é uma [SPA<sup>en</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) feita com Backbone.

Primeiramente: a API aceita apenas requisições HTTPS, no caso de um *request* HTTP chegar no servidor ele o ignora completamente e opcionalment pode invalidar a senha utilizada naquele *request* não seguro.

Meu servidor não guarda estado (sem sessão/cookies) e eu uso apenas [autenticação HTTP básica<sup>en</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), onde forneço duas maneiras de se autenticar um *request*:

1- Enviar as credenciais no *header*: `Authentication: base64('Basic ' + nomeDeUsuario:senha)`
2- Enviar um request autenticado com o método 1 para `GET /usuarios/atual` que retorna um token, que é uma string criptografada* contendo: `nomeDeUsuario + '|' + dataDeExpiracaoDoToken`. O cliente daí então passa a enviar o *header* `Authentication: 'Token ' + base64(nomeDeUsuario:token)`.

<sub>*Criptografia feita com algoritmo aes-256-ctr do OpenSSL. A chave privada é o hash da senha do usuário.</sub>

O **método 1** pode ser utilizado para comunicação servidor-servidor, portanto não é adequado ao cliente JavaScript, pois para todos os requests o usuário teria que inserir suas credenciais, a menos que tais credenciais fossem armazenadas na memória do browser, *o que eu não sei se é seguro o suficiente*. Além do mais, armazenar as credencias no *local storage* manteria o usuário logado indefinidamente.

Pelo **método 2** o cliente JavaScript envia apenas um request autenticado com autenticação básica e imediatamente descarta essas informações sensíveis de login, armazenando apenas o token no local storage. Após um determinado tempo este token irá expirar e será necessário uma revalidação, *quase que emulando uma sessão no servidor*.

Do lado do servidor eu verifico a autenticidade de um request feito com o método 2 simplesmente obtendo o hash da senha do usuario e tentando descriptografar o token, então eu verifico `tokenDescriptografado.split('|')[0] === username`.

Esta á uma abordagem segura? Existe algum ponto que não estou levando em consideração? Dada esta abordagem, quais tipo de ataques eu estaria sujeito?

<sub>*Este é um [crosspost](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125/posso-fazer-crosspost-entre-o-so-em-ingl%C3%AAs-e-o-so-em-portugu%C3%AAs) de [uma pergunta que fiz no Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74498/is-this-a-good-approach-to-secure-my-rest-api)</sub>

Comment: [essas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42922/qual-a-forma-correta-de-fazer-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-uma-api-rest-usada-por-aplicativos?rq=1) [duas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33118/como-funciona-a-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-um-ambiente-restful-stateless/33120#33120) perguntas de certa forma se relacionam com a minha

Comment: Já cogitou SSL com OAuth2?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto vou dar uma lida agora sobre OAuth2. No caso seria como se eu mesmo fosse o provedor de identidade!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há um problema em seu método 2: suponha que um atacante obtenha uma cópia do seu BD. Normalmente isso não seria uma catástrofe, pois as senhas dos usuários estão hasehadas, mas pelo método 2 o atacante poderia se autenticar somente com o hash:

1. Crie um novo token `nomeDeUsuario + '|' + dataDeExpiracaoDoToken`, com uma data de expiração recente;
2. Use o hash desse usuário para criptografar o token, e envie-o. O servidor aceitará a autenticação!

Um método mais seguro de gerar tokens no servidor sem guardar estado é através de uma assinatura (ou melhor dizendo, um HMAC): guarde da maneira mais segura que puder (ex.: um arquivo de configurações com acesso restrito, ou um módulo de hardware) uma chave secreta conhecida somente pelo servidor. Não coloque essa chave no BD. Quando um usuário acessar `/usuarios/atual`, crie um token tal como estava fazendo (nome de usuário e data de expiração), mas em vez de criptografá-lo com o hash da senha do usuário, assine-o usando esse segredo:

```
HMAC(segredo, token)
```

E envie ambos ao usuário (o token em texto plano, e a assinatura do token). Quando o usuário repassar esses dados ao servidor, verifique se a assinatura está intacta (o usuário *poderia* alterar o nome de usuário ou a data de expiração no token em texto plano, mas ele não poderia falsificar a assinatura sem o segredo do servidor). Dessa forma, um atacante com acesso somente ao hash da senha do usuário não poderia se autenticar usando o método 1, nem forjar um token para ser usado no método 2.

Isso deixaria seu sistema mais seguro num cenário como este, em que o atacante tem uma cópia do seu BD mas não do seu sistema como um todo (ex.: numa vazamento via Injeção de SQL, obtém-se uma cópia do banco, mas os arquivos de configuração/módulo de hardware continuam intactos). E se esses tokens tem curta duração, pode ser interessante nem usar um segredo persistente, mas sim gerar uma chave aleatória em memória, válida somente até o servidor ser reiniciado (se há múltiplos servidores, com balanceamento de carga por exemplo, isso pode ser menos viável).

Comment: Nota: assim como você fez *crosspost* no security.SE, eu [respondi lá também](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/82971/6939), de forma mais direta ao ponto entretanto (enquanto aqui eu respondi de forma mais didática).

Comment: É verdade, muito boa sua observação! Eu estou pensando se poderia usar um algoritmo baseado em data/hora ou num seed para expirar o segredo a cada 10 minutos por exemplo. Mas acho que dá no mesmo pois o problema seria esconder o seed ao invés do segredo! Obrigado pela reposta!

Comment: Dificilmente um atacante vai conseguir ler a memória do seu servidor (e se ele conseguir, você está frito de qualquer maneira); a menos que esses tokens de autenticação tenham que sobreviver a um restart no servidor, manter o segredo em memória já é bom o bastante. Gere algo aleatório usando `/dev/urandom` (ou equivalente) quando o sistema iniciar e, se o servidor reiniciar por qualquer motivo, faça o usuário se reautenticar pelo método 1. É inconveniente, sim, mas muito raro, e mais seguro que armazenar esse segredo/seed num arquivo (e mais barato que usar um módulo de hardware).